# Does NPM ignore files listed in .gitignore?

Tags: node.js, git, npm

I have a file that is generated by `npm install` command (using `preinstall` task). I don't want to add it in the git repository, nor in the NPM project.

Supposing the file name is `foo.json`, I added it in `.gitignore` file as `foo.json`.

Is this enough to avoid uploading it on NPM registry?

I know I can add `.npmignore` file that will surely ignore the file, but I won't add it if `.gitignore` already does this.

Answer (score 158, accepted):

If a project has both `.npmignore` and `.gitignore`, npm will **only** use the `.npmignore` file.

From [the documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/using-npm/developers#keeping-files-out-of-your-package):

> Use a `.npmignore` file to keep stuff out of your package. If there's no `.npmignore` file, but there *is* a `.gitignore` file, then npm will ignore the stuff matched by the `.gitignore` file. If you *want* to include something that is excluded by your `.gitignore` file, you can create an empty `.npmignore` file to override it.

In simpler terms, npm *prefers* the `.npmignore` file, but it will fall back to the `.gitignore` file.

In many cases, both Git and npm can ignore the same files, so it makes sense to just use a `.gitignore` file.

**If you need npm and Git to ignore different files, then you need to maintain separate `.gitignore` and `.npmignore` files.**

*More information on what to put in `.npmignore` files: [Should I .npmignore my tests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25124844/should-i-npmignore-my-tests)*

Comment: It have a different situation, but quite similar, I have a `.gitignore` that excludes a dir `bin/` where my transcompiled ES6 app goes, so I can push `lib/`, the ES6 written app. But, as you may figure out, the problem is that the published package in npm must have the `bin/`

Comment: Sounds like you need an `.npmignore` file containing the same contents as `.gitignore` but with the `bin/` line removed.

Comment: I want the complete opposite. I want npm to add a folder, despite it being present in .gitignore

Comment: @LajosMeszaros the second sentence covers that: “If you want to include something that is excluded by your `.gitignore` file, you can create an empty `.npmignore` file to override it.” In your case you will need to copy `.gitignore` to `.npmignore`, and remove the folder from `.npmignore` only.

Answer (score 33):

For anyone reading this trying to ignore a file/dir from git but wish to include it in npm publish and have tried using an empty `.npmignore` file with no luck. This works.

In your `.gitignore` file, add the file/dir you wish to exclude `**/build` for example and in your `.npmignore` file make sure you specify the same file/dir but with the `!` prefix so for the build example you would include `!**/build`