# How to npm disable only CSS file from module?

Tags: css, node.js, angular, npm

Many times I have faced the following issue detailed below.

I use the NPM module that works fine except the fact that I need to erase all predefined CSS rules to make it consistent with the website design.

Is there a way to ignore a CSS file from the NPM module or is there an alternative to solve this issue?

Comment: can you give an example of an npm module where you need to do this?

Comment: This answer might be what you're looking for:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/24942436/4266776

Comment: If styles from NPM are automatically getting bundled into your website without being explicitly referenced then you have a bigger problem with your build pipeline. Are you using a seed project or Angular CLI to scaffold your application?

Comment: @mihai real example https://github.com/akveo/ng2-smart-table it is an ng2 smart table plugin that have an ugly style and no way to override default table style by a bootstrap table other than forking the repo

Comment: @JesseCarter I use Angular CLI and they are getting automatically bundled I find this good

Comment: This is not the default behavior of Angular CLI. Are you including paths to the NPM styles in the `styles` array of angular-cli.json?

Comment: @JesseCarter yes sometimes. and sometimes it works without the need to include style uri in angular-cli.json don't really understund the process and how it happens