# Error installing my published package in npm registry - Errorno - 4058. No such file or directory main.js error

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, npm-install

I created a sample package and published it into npm registry under my own npm account. Name of my package is `newtestmay`. Now when I try to install it using the command `npm install newtestmay` I get below error. I've copied the error level logs out of the entire log from `npm-debug.log` file which got created by npm in the root of my package where I'm trying to install the package:

> 128 error Windows_NT 6.1.7601
>
> 129 error argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "install"
>   "newtestmay"
>
> 130 error node v6.9.1
>
> 131 error npm  v3.10.8
>
> 132 error path D:\rbt\math_user\node_modules\newtestmay\main.js
>
> 133 error code ENOENT
>
> 134 error errno -4058
>
> 135 error syscall chmod
>
> 136 error enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, chmod
>   'D:\rbt\math_user\node_modules\newtestmay\main.js'
>
> 137 error enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, chmod
>   'D:\rbt\math_user\node_modules\newtestmay\main.js'
>
> 137 error enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
>
> 137 error enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
>
> 138 verbose exit [ -4058, true ]

`package.json` of my `newtestmay` package which I had published:

```
{
  "name": "newtestmay",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "an example of creating a package",
  "main": "bin/main.js",
  "bin": {
    "mathexample22may": "main.js"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "math",
    "example",
    "addition",
    "subtraction",
    "multiplication",
    "division",
    "fibonacci"
  ],
  "author": "rasik210",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Directory structure of my package:

[image]

Code of `main.js`:

```
var path = require('path');
var fs = require('fs');
var lib = path.join(path.dirname(fs.realpathSync(__filename)), '../lib');
var simple = require(lib + '/simple_math.js');
var advanced = require(lib + '/advanced_math.js');
module.exports = {
addition: simple.addition,
subtraction: simple.subtraction,
multiplication: advanced.multiplication,
division: advanced.division,
fibonacci: advanced.fibonacci
}
```

I'm not able to understand as to why NPM is unable to see `main.js` which was present in the `bin` directory when I had published the package.

Comment: Is `bin/main.js` a compiled file? If so and you have a `.gitignore` which ignores it, then it will not be published to NPM. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24942161/does-npm-ignore-files-listed-in-gitignore

Comment: My application code is not under any source control including git. It is a nodeJs application. Although I'm new to nodeJs but I believe the code written in `main.js` is plain javascript and there is no case of compilation or tanspilation which happens in other javascript frameworks like reactJs. I've added the source code of `main.js` file in my post for reference.

Comment: Oh I thought you meant that the `main.js` file is not included in the package, but it just looks like the reference is wrong. I think you need a relative path in the `bin` section of `package.json`. Try using: `"mathexample22may": "./bin/main.js"`.

Comment: ohh. Wow! It just worked. Man you saved my day. Being a novice on npm, I had been struggling on this since yesterday morning. Now I realize it was a typographical error in the book itself I was referring to. Thanks a ton! You might want to add this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple typo: The `bin` object of `package.json` is all relative to the root of the project. In this case, it should be:

```
{
    ...
    "bin": {
      "mathexample22may": "./bin/main.js"
    },
    ...
}
```