# Include .gitignored files compiled from typescript in `npm install -g`

Tags: typescript, npm, gitignore

I'd like to ignore the JavaScript files compiled from TypeScript in my git repo. (That greatly simplifies merging, rebasing, partial commits etc.)  The relevant parts of my setup look like this:

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "outDir": "./dist"
    }
}
```

**.gitignore**

```
dist
```

When installing globally like this:

```
rm -rf dist
node_modules/.bin/tsc
sudo npm install -g
```

the gitignored `dist` folder is not installed. Is there any proper solution to this? The following ones aren't really satisfactory:

- Comment/uncomment `dist` in `.gitignore` before and after `sudo npm install -g`
- Cope with parallelly managing ts and js files

Comment: make sure you don't have "noEmit": true,  in your tsconfig.json

Comment: @TWI I have no `noEmit` set. In any case, I don't think that's relevant to the problem, is it?

Comment: No I didn't fully understand what npm install -g did, So it appears npm install -g honours .gitignore? This might answer your problem https://stackoverflow.com/a/24942436/3343178

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the problem by putting the following into my `package.json`:

```
"files": [
  "/dist"
],
```

Now, only the dist folder and `README.md` are packaged/installed. Found out about this possibility from a [post by Jeff Dickey](https://medium.com/@jdxcode/for-the-love-of-god-dont-use-npmignore-f93c08909d8d#5360).